# NoClassDefFoundError problems with help of Apache Commons Validator

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

Getting an error if using Apache Commons Validator:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/oro/text/perl/Perl5Util

Even if, Apache Commons Validator /dependencies state that ORO.jar is optional.

Comment: When the dependencies report for commons-validator says that oro is "optional", it means it's optional unless you are using classes that require it - which you must be if you get this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the jar containing "org/apache/oro/text/perl/Perl5Util" class on the server and modify the classpath of the server to include the jar file.

Comment: I searched again for Jakarta Oro.jar (which isn't given in their official website) and found it here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/ABC/Downloadjakartaorojar.htm

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue on version 1.3.1 of Apache's Validator.  I rolled back to 1.3.0 and it included the oro dependency just fine.

If you don't rely on something from the dot release, perhaps this could work for you as well.

Comment: I confirm I had the bug with validator 1.3.1 depandencies and rolling back to 1.3.0 solved the problem. I would recommend this answer until Apache solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The newer version (1.4.0) of commons-validator has no dependency on oro anymore.
Using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're using something that requires that class.

Compiler wins over documentation.

Comment: Yes, It required Jakarta Oro jar file. Which was written optional in Apache Commons Validator dependencies list. So din't included in classpath. But now just included it and its working. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Apache oro. I've version 2.0.8 though Maven and it has Perl5Util:

```
mpandit-mbp:2.0.8 mpandit$ jar tvf oro-2.0.8.jar | grep 'Perl5Util'
7818 Sun Dec 28 23:00:18 PST 2003 org/apache/oro/text/perl/Perl5Util.class
```

Comment: Though! I got Jakarta Oro jar file. And code is working now. I will keep this information for future references. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this dependency to get Perl5Util.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>oro</groupId>
     <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```