# Build fails on running ant script

Tags: ant

When I try to run an ant script (./ant clean or ./ant setup), my build fails with:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.oro.text.perl.Perl5Util

I found something similar at [NoClassDefFoundError problems with help of Apache Commons Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706914/noclassdeffounderror-problems-with-help-of-apache-commons-validator), but this is my first brush with ant and I'm lost on the jargon. Could you please elaborate if I'm having the same issue, and what it is (in layman terms)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ant version from 1.8.3 to 1.7.1 in my user.properties and it worked. Turns out, 1.8.x in our repository doesn't have the p4 integration files. Why it's there in the repository in the first place is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jar file missing.  Maybe you can get it [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/)