# org.apache.commons.validator.EmailValidator

Tags: java, apache

I am trying to validate the email: **hello.world@cir.care**

```
boolean isValidEmail = EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid("hello.world@cir.care")
```

It throws error when I use `commonvalidator 1.14` but its works with `1.5.1`

**Error StackTrace:**

> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive null                                org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/oro/text/perl/Perl5Util

boths the jars are available in server path.

Please suggest me if I miss any thing?

Answer (score 0):

Download and add the following jar in your server path [apache-jakarta-oro.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachejakartaorojar.htm)

Also refer the following link for more options
[NoClassDefFoundError problems with help of Apache Commons Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706914/noclassdeffounderror-problems-with-help-of-apache-commons-validator)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven add this dependency to the project repository

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>oro</groupId>
      <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8</version>
  </dependency>
```